# How to add a NSDrawer in Storyboard of Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7

I'd like to have a NSDrawer slide out/in of the left side of a window, like:

[image]

How can I do that in a storyboard inside Interface Builder? The is no match when I type NSDrawer in the control search bar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "Window and Drawer."  If you search NSDrawer, you won't find anything, but if you search for "Window and Drawer" or "NSWindow," it should come up.

Comment: It's available for xib, not storyboard.